# Lower batch size in the last iteration of first training epoch than the other iteration

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, training-data

I'm trying to train an deep neural network model, the output dimensions of each iteration in one epoch is like [64,1600,8] (64 is the batch size). But in the last iteration of first epoch, this output changed to [54,1600,8] and faced with dimension error. Why in the last iteration batch size had changed??
Additionally, if I change the batch size to 32 the last iteration's output is [22,1600,8].

I think that the output of the last iteration must be same as the other iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that you are using pytorch, I'll add to the answer by Richard by saying that pytorch DataLoaders have the functionality built-in to drop the last (incomplete) batch. Checking the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html), you can specify `drop_last=True` while instantiating the DataLoader.

Answer (score 4):

The last iteration batch size changed because you did not have enough data to completely fill the batch. If you have a batch size of 10, for example, and you have 101 entries total in your data, then you will have 10 batches of 10 and 1 batch of 1.

The solution is to either drop the batch if it is not the correct size, or to adapt your model so that it will detect the size of the batch and change accordingly, instead of having the batch size hard-coded in to your model parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the datasets doesn't matter. I try to trained my model on different datasets, but again it has problem with last iteration.

Comment: What are your suggestions to adapt the model? I could not drop the last batch because of DataLoader configuration of my course.

Comment: @Lambchop123 If you are unable to change the DataLoader configuration, you can either modify the datafile ahead of time (i.e. taking the number of lines of data modulo the batch size), or you can put a check in your actual model that skips a batch if it isn't complete.